# Efficiently concatenating the JSON column type in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, database

My API responds to queries that may return around 100,000 models called MOFs. Each model has a json column called 'pregen_json' that caches the current state of the model. This is cached because generating the json in real time is too slow (~40ms/model * 100,000 models = 1 Hr). Here's the relevant bit of schema (running mySQL) + code:

Schema:

```
  create_table "mofs", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.json "pregen_json"
  end
```

Controller:

```
        # some filtering of @mofs to respond to search query omitted
        render :json => @mofs.pluck(:pregen_json)
```

Time to download based on the length of @mofs [m:s]

1,000 --> 0:10

10,000 --> 2:00

100,000 --> 7:00

Basically the user sees 90% wait time with no data and then everything is sent at once after the server prepares the response.

Looking for suggestions on how to speed this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to avoid extremely long API calls, people do paginate their results. The client asks for a certain page (and/or a certain amount of results) and the server returns just that.

There are many pagination ruby gems like [Will Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) or [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) that will help you do that.

Otherwise it is fairly simple to implement basic pagination yourself by using limit and offset `Model.limit(PAGE_SIZE).offset(PAGE_SIZE * page_number)`.

You might want to add buttons so the client can select the page he wants to load. If your wish is to load everything, then you can create a loop that keeps requesting the next pages until there is no data returned anymore. The advantage here is that the data will load over time instead of all at once after a long period of time.

Apart from that, I am surprised that fetching 100,000 record takes 7 minutes. You might want to put only the necessary information in that pre-generated JSON to limit the quantity of data being pulled from the database to the client.

I hope this helps you take a decision. Good luck!